# Adding dynamic iOS app banner meta tag in Angular

Tags: ios, angular

When dynamically adding a iOS app banner `meta` tag to an Angular 10 app, I can see that the tag is indeed added under the `head` tag, but Safari on iOS never shows the app banner. I suspect that this may have something to do with the page's `head` already having been parsed by Safari, before the `meta` tag is added.

When I say dynamically, it's because I only want to show the app banner on certain routes of the Angular app. If I add the meta tag manually in the `index.html` page, then the banner appears as expected.

This is an example of what an iOS app banner tag looks like: `<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=12345">`

The way that I have been able to add the `meta` tag is by creating a resolver service:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
 import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
 import { Meta } from "@angular/platform-browser";

 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })

 export class MobileAppBannerResolveService implements Resolve<Observable<string>> {
   constructor(
     private metaService: Meta
   ) {}

   resolve(): Observable<string> {
     this.metaService.addTag({ name: 'apple-itunes-app', content: 'app-id=12345' });
     return of(null);
   }

   // Remove the `meta` tag from the HTML page
   cleanup(): void {
     this.metaService.removeTag("name='apple-itunes-app'");
   }
 }
```

I add this resolver in the Route (here's an example snippet):

```
  {
    path: 'charts',
    component: ChartComponent,
    children: chartRoutes,
    resolve: {
        mobileApp: MobileAppBannerResolveService
    }
  }
```

And then include it in the component, via the constructor:

```
 constructor(
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private mobileAppBannerResolveService: MobileAppBannerResolveService
   ) {}
```

At this point, the `meta` tag is added by virtue of the service's `resolve()` method.

Finally, when leaving that page, I remove the tag in the `ngOnDestroy`:

```
   ngOnDestroy(): void {
     this.mobileAppBannerResolveService.cleanup();
   }
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? Or do I just need to include the tag in the `index.html` and have it be in every route in the Angular app? I did have a look to see if there were any hooks in navigation that were early in the lifecycle, but to no avail. e.g. I tried `NavigationEnd`.